# Mail server with different IP than webserver - getting 554 error

Tags: domain-name-system, email, smtp, spf

I have a webshop running on a Digital Ocean droplet, while the email inbox for the same domain is running on a different VPS. All of the sudden some of the emails sent by the webshop are being rejected by the recipient with the following error message:

```
host mx01.emig.gmx.net[XX.XXX.XX.XXX (Receiver IP adress)] refused to
    talk to me: 554-gmx.net (mxgmx104) Nemesis ESMTP Service not available
    554-No SMTP service 554 invalid DNS PTR resource record, IP=XX.XXX.XX.XXX (IP of the webshop)
```

I already added a SPF-Record with the following content:

```
v=spf1 a mx ~all
```

With the a-record of the domain pointing to the webserver and the mx-record pointing to the server which hosts the email inbox.

Is there something wrong with the SPF-record or is there a problem somewhere else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guidelines for Mail Servers - How to Maximize Deliverability to Remote Inboxes](http://serverfault.com/questions/76761/guidelines-for-mail-servers-how-to-maximize-deliverability-to-remote-inboxes)

Comment: You need to create a reverse DNS (PTR) record for any IP addresses which send mail.

Answer (score 2):

You should set rDNS (PTR) record for the IP address (IP of the webshop), as the recipient mail server is rejecting the mail due to invalid or no PTR (rDNS) record for the IP address from where the mail is originated.

Comment: Just to add, when you set up a rDNS record, make sure it's non-generic. Generic rDNS records will get rejected at various ESPs. You can test to see if generic or not by sending an email to mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com.  You can also read more about it here: [PTR Records](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/ptrrecords/)